# How can I publish/upload ASP.NET MVC 5 Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ftp, publishing

I have never published an ASP.NET MVC website to a hosted server. I have read and followed instructions and failed with publishing from Visual Studio directly to the hosted server. I used FTP publish method, provided required credentials, then published the website successfully. When I do this, I get the error when I try to access the website:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I thus followed another instruction to publish to a local folder, using File System method, then uploaded the contents of that local folder using ftp to the hosted server. This gives me this error when I try to access the website:

> Server Error
> 403 Forbidden
> You do not have permission to access this document.

I would have loved the second method to work, but looking at the folder content, I can see some folders like App_Start missing, which I know is where start up pages are managed from, so I am not sure whether this is a proper procedure.

I would love some advice on how to publish this website. It would also be great to find a way that will allow updating changes, instead of publishing the entire website whenever changes are made.

I am using VS2019, and a .net hosting provider, not Azure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most case you can't see `App_Start` but all can working fine, you should find `httpdocs` it's the destination folder that you need to use to copy your files.

You can also try **web deploy** in your visual studio.
To make it work correctly you need to get the setup file from your hosting provider, with this you don't need to update always all files by ftp, and if you are lucky (if you have Database rights) you can also auto-update your database.

Don't forget also to check your `web.config` if you use a database connection.

Please try this two methods then if you need more help I will edit.

Comment: Thanks! Let me give this a shot. I already took care of the web.config because it is visible. I will feedback...

Comment: Turns out that a) I appended a non-required {user_}dbname in the connectionstring, and b) the host needed to update my VPS from .net 4.7 to 4.8, since I built the application in .net 4.7.2

I will tick this as the answer because you pointed me to the right direction!

Comment: Also to make this work for me, this part has been commented out in Web.config:     <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
I will investigate further what it does/does not do